# Check radio button in RadioButtonList based on text value read from database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

In the user interface, i have radio button list which contains (Level One, Level Two, Level Three). On the other hand, I have student table(ID,name,level,DOB,....) which save the the student's level as varchar. 
In page load, i want to fill the radioButtonList based on the value read from database.
the following code is running but it does not check the suitble radio button which read it from DB.

```
using (MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
                {
                    MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT S_Id, level FROM student where S_Id='" + 111 + "'"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = SqlCon;
                        SqlCon.Open();
                        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(myReader.ToString()) != null)
                        {
                           // RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(myReader.ToString()).Selected = true;
                            RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = myReader.ToString();
                        }

                        SqlCon.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is your code which you are calling to get the data from database is in postback check?

Comment: yes, I put this code inside:  if (!this.IsPostBack) {...My Code...}

Comment: radioButtonList1.Items.FindByText("Your Text").Selected = true; or you can also do with Items Index RadioButtonList.Items[1].Selected = true;

Comment: RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue is fine. can you post your itemsource example. Is myReader.ToString() is part of value from itemssource?

Comment: I need from the code to :1) select the level from database which the s_Id=111. 2) this level should be checked by program. For example, student A who has id=111 in the level two. the program read the level from DB and check on radiobuttonlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to traverse through the DataReader object to get its values. Try something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
   MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
   using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT S_Id, level FROM student where S_Id='" + 111 + "'"))
 {
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Connection = SqlCon;
  SqlCon.Open();
  myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (myReader.Read())
  {
   if (RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(myReader["level"].ToString()) != null)
   {                           
     RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = myReader["level"].ToString();
   }               
  }
  sqlCon.Close();
 }
}
```